# Date.parse fails when system date is 2017-02-01

Tags: ruby

I'm experiencing an strange issue with Date.parse method.

I tried several ruby versions and it happens in all of them. The tests below were run in version 2.1.10.

Yesterday all my tests were passing but today they started to fail. The cause is a Date.parse call that started to raise an exception.

If system date is 2017-01-31, it works fine:

```
2.1.10 :002 > system('date')
Ter 31 Jan 2017 11:24:08 BRST
 => true
2.1.10 :003 > Date.parse("29%2F10%2F2015")
 => #<Date: 2017-01-29 ((2457783j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

But if system date is today, it fails:

```
2.1.10 :002 > system('date')
Qua  1 Fev 2017 11:24:27 BRST
 => true
2.1.10 :003 > Date.parse("29%2F10%2F2015")
ArgumentError: invalid date
        from (irb):3:in `parse'
        from (irb):3
        from /Users/fernando/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I probably can get around this by using another method to parse this date but I'm interested in why it started to fail today.

Is 2017-02-01 a special date for ruby?

Comment: Does `29%2F10%2F2015` look like a date for you?

Comment: @axiac Yes, but it's url encoded.

Comment: Then url-decode it first. `Date` doesn't know about url encoding. And, btw, `29%2F10%2F2015` is `29/10/2015`, not `2017-01-29` as it is "parsed" by ruby in your first example. How do you mean this "works fine"?

Comment: It's url encoded and it's actually the `2015-10-29` not the `2015-01-29` so your first attempt is already wrong...

Answer (score 3):

`Date.parse` is a method which tries to parse a date from the given string using a number of heuristics in order to support many different formats without specifying the actual format. Thus, unless the format is clear, it is always possible that Ruby come to different conclusions than you.

In order to get an idea how Ruby parses your string, you can use

```
Date._parse("29%2F10%2F2015")
# => {:mday=>29}
```

As you can see, Ruby is able to get the day of month as 29 from the passed string but doesn't get any additional information. In order to form a valid date, Ruby substitutes the missing parts from the current date. Now, since February 2017 only has 28 days, the resulting date is invalid here but would be valid in January.

Still, the result is not what you actually seem to want. Instead, try to first transform your date into a more easily parsed string and try again using the approach by Eric Duminil in another answer to this question:

```
require 'date'
require 'uri'

string = '29%2F10%2F2015'
Date.strptime(URI.unescape(string), '%d/%m/%Y')
# => #<Date: 2015-10-29 ((2457325j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

As you can see, with [`Date.strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime), you can specify the exact format of the parsed string and can thus be sure it either gets correctly parsed or errors out.

Comment: It is (I just credited you explicitly). The important part of the answer is the first half though.

Comment: Better than nothing, thanks. Do you happen to know which method is called to get the current date by `Date.parse`?

Comment: It calls the C-method implementing `Date.today` (i.e. `date_s_today` from `ext/date/date_core.c`). However, since this is internally in C, it doesn't seem to use Ruby's higher-level method dispatcher which is why overriding `Date.today` doesn't change this.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`%2F` is the URL Encoded value of the Forward Slash (`/`)

so you need to **`decode`** your **`url-encoded string`**  first

```
> require 'open-uri'
#=> true 
> string = "29%2F10%2F2015"
#=> "29%2F10%2F2015" 
> date = URI::decode(string)
#=> "29/10/2015" 
> Date.parse(date)
#=> #<Date: 2015-10-29 ((2457325j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

> Is 2017-02-01 a special date for ruby?

no, it's not special ;)

```
> s = "2017-02-01"
> Date.parse(s)
#=> #<Date: 2017-02-01 ((2457786j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Looks much better now :-)

Comment: If OP doesn't get reliable results, `Date.parse` isn't the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

You have three problems :

- '%2F' shouldn't be here
- '2017-02-01' could be "February 1" or "January 2".
- `Date.parse` relies on system date to parse the string.

If you know which format you have, you really should use [`Date.strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) :

```
require 'date'
require 'uri'

def parse_url_date(url_date)
  Date.strptime(URI.unescape(url_date), '%d/%m/%Y')
end

puts parse_url_date("29%2F10%2F2015")
#=> 2015-10-29
puts parse_url_date("01%2F02%2F2017")
#=> 2017-02-01
```

Comment: (1) `Date.parse` does not shellout to the base-OS's `date` executable. It has its own heuristics. (2) `Date.parse` is able to correctly parse ISO8601 strings and prefers `YYYY-MM-DD` to `YYYY-DD-MM`. Using `strptime` is still a better idea though. +1 for that.

Comment: I cannot explain why the current date would have any influence on date.parse otherwise. I successfully reproduced the questions behavior by changing system date. Using timecop gem wasn't enough

Comment: See my answer regarding the influence of the current date :)

Comment: `02-01` is ambiguous; `2017-02-01` is not. Most of the world uses D-M-Y, America uses M-D-Y, Japan uses Y-M-D (and so should any coder), but no-one uses Y-D-M.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your "dates" are URL-encoded then you have to URL-decode them first. Use [`URI.unescape()`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-unescape) for this then pass the value it returns to [`Date.parse()`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse).

```
Date.parse(URI.unescape("29%2F10%2F2015"))
```